# Styling a Calculator in Html/CSS/Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, calculator

I am trying to create my first project in CSS - a calculator. But I have got a problem with putting the cells in a perfect column. I want all cells to be the same size. (Except  " = ") Would be nice if you could give me some advice. Thanks in advance.
I've already come this far:

## Calculator

```
<div class ="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="First Row">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="7"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="8"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="9"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="+"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Second Row">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="4"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="5"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="6"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="-"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Third Row">

        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="1"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="2"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="3"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="*"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Fourth Row">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="0"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="."></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="+/-"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="/"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="="></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look hope you find it help. If still any issue or question please ask.

```css
.btn{
  width:50px;
  min-width:50px; /* this for smallest devices */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class ="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="First Row">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="7"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="8"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="9"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="+"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Second Row">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="4"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="5"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="6"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="-"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Third Row">

        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="1"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="2"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="3"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="*"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Fourth Row">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="0"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="."></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="+/-"></input>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="/"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark" waves-effect value="="></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NiklasFlink Your Welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS grids for creating the calculator. The numbers will act as different row and  column elements of same width. For the '=', you can span it across multiple columns if you want it to be of greater width or span it across multiple rows if you want to be greater in height.

Answer (score 0):

For perfect column you can use the grid system:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class ="col-2">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="7"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="8"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="9"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="+"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="4"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="5"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="6"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="-"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="1"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="2"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="3"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="*"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="0"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="."></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="+/-"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-3" waves-effect value="/"></input>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-dark col-12" waves-effect value="="></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```